# How to get BTC and ETH prices from Binance in Google Sheets?

Tags: api, binance, cryptofinance

I've been using the `CRYPTOFINANCE()` function in Google Sheets for a while but I can't seem to find out how to pull data from my exchange (Binance).

I'm specifically looking for the BTC/USD and ETH/USD markets. Using the syntax in the doc[1](https://cryptofinance.ai/docs/how-to-get-data-from-binance/) gives me #ERROR in my cells.
My syntax is `=CRYPTOFINANCE("BINANCE:BTC/USD")`

Anybody had this problem before and managed to fix it?

Comment: Binance has a public API you can possibly query for these purposes. Also keep in mind Binance isnt a regulated exchange and therefore uses stable coins(most notably USDT) and not actual USD for its markets.

Comment: I think this belongs to the Bitcoin Stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my question.

Leon had a point in his comment, Binance doesn't have USD pairs, only USDT.

I updated my cryptofinance calls to `=CRYPTOFINANCE("BINANCE:BTC/USDT")` and `=CRYPTOFINANCE("BINANCE:ETH/USDT")` and it worked like a charm!